# Problem in setting workspace on eclipse 3.4.1 ganymede

Tags: eclipse, environment, workspace

I don't have totroise SVN installed at this moment on my desktop. But i have .svn folders in my projects. After importing the projects into the workspace on eclipse, there is one project for which i get the following error...

The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/systemcommon/build/classes/.svn'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

I am not able to delete the .svn folder from '/systemcommon/build/classes/ as it says "Could not delete all-wcprops: Access is denied"

Need help...

Comment: Shutdown eclipse and any running instances of your program. Then try to remove the files manually.